# Delimiter for meta data in Windows file name

Tags: windows, character, filenames, delimiter

I'm working on maintenance of an application that transfers a file to another system and uses a structured filename to include meta data including a language code.  The current app uses a two character language code and a dash/hyphen for a delimiter.

Ex. Canada-EN-ProdName-ProdCode.txt

I'm converting it to use IETF language code and so the dash delimiter won't do and need a replacement.  I'm trying to determine a delimiter to avoid future errors and am considering the tilde ~.

Ex. Canada~en-GB~ProdName~ProdCode.txt

This will be use only on Windows Sever 2003 + systems.  I certainly didn't come up with this system of parsing a filename to get meta data.  Unfortunately, I can't include this in the file itself and the destination system is expecting the language code to be in IETF format with the dash.

Any thoughts on potential issues with using the tilde in the filename, or perhaps a better character to use?  I'm just looking for a second opinion in case I'm overlooking a possible failure.  I believe windows will use the tilde when shortening a long filename to 8.3 format, but I don't see that as an issue here as the OSs can handle lang filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde is probably fine, but what's wrong with the good old underscore _ ?  It has no special meaning on either windows or unix, and makes names that are relatively easy to read.  If there are no other special considerations, I would avoid the tilde solely out of paranoia, since windows does use it as a special character sometimes, as you mentioned.

Comment: a quick scan of the IETF spec on wikipedia didn't say anything about underscores being allowed in a code, so that shouldn't be a problem either.

Comment: Wow, yeah. Glad I asked, I'm not sure how I forgot about the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone readiong this question I would strongly recommend anything but the tilde in the file name or at least be careful in testing for any speed problems with any .NET path work where one exists.

I used this as a file name delimiter some time ago.  I couldn't understand why simply getting a list of files from the folders was taking so long. It was a number of years later (having written a lot of speed up code that had marginal advantage) that I discovered there is a problem with the (DirectoryInfo(path).name in .NET at least) where simple existience of the tilde was forcing underlying code to through a lot of hoops.

The slow down was substantial (it was over a network so I had thought it was bandwidth/Network issues for a fair while)

I understand this is a legacy overhang for when alternative short versions of filenames could be used for Windows files.

I am now stuck with the tilde in these file names but, given that the problem lay in some of the .NET path functions (I don't actually know if it still does), I could work around it by spotting a tilde and creating my own answers when it existed rather than passing it through.

If in any doubt just run speed tests with and without the tilde in filenames for say just 500-1,000 files.